# RegEx validate name and email

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate email format with name that can handle both patterns

**Valid**

1. `test@domain.com`
2. `test user <test@domain.com>`
3. `test user<test@domain.com>`
4. `"test user" <test@domain.com>`
5. `"test user"<test@domain.com>`

**Invalid**

1. `"test user" <test@domain.com`
2. `"test user" test@domain.com>`
3. `test user <test@domain.com`
4. `test user test@domain.com>`
5. `"test user <test@domain.com>`
6. `test user" <test@domain.com>`
7. `"test user" test@domain.com`

here's my progress:
https://regex101.com/r/Q00McL/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar OP's requirements are slightly different

Comment: It is correct that the last one `"test user" test@domain.com` should be valid, like `^(?:(?:"[^"\r\n]+"|\w+(?: +\w+)*) *)?\w+@[^<>\s@]+\.\w{2,3}$` https://regex101.com/r/lPYQL6/1

Answer (score 0):

Why are items `4. "test user" test@domain.com (valid)` and `7. "test user" test@domain.com (invalid)` the same?

If you want `"test user" test@domain.com` to be valid use this pattern:

```
^(?:(?:"[^"\r\n]+"|\w+(?: +\w+)*) *)?\w+@[^<>\s@]+\.\w{2,3}$
```

On the contrary, if `"test user" test@domain.com` should be invalid use:

```
^(?:(?:"[^"\r\n]+"|\w+(?: +\w+)*)*)?\w+@[^<>\s@]+\.\w{2,3}$
```

Comment: Sorry. format did not display < >